# FTP files from one remote server to another

Tags: ftp, perl

I am trying to find out how I can transfer files from one directory/server to another directory/server?

What I need to consider is that I should transfer files that are created TODAY only. i.e. the folder will look like this:

```
04/20/2012 <n files>
04/14/2012 <m files>
```

and if I am running the job today, the script should transfer only the `n` files that were created today.

Can anyone please help me out how I should do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how strict is your requirement: *only the files that were created today*.

If you're ok with *only the files that **have changed (or are new)***, 
then a possible solution is:

```
ssh user1@server1 rsync -urv path/to/dir/ user2@server2:/path/to/dir/
```